# How can i build apk from ionic + react + capacitor project?

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

I wonder why i can't find **build bundle(s)/APK** in my android studio, i am using Ionic, React and Capacitor to build my project before directing to complete my work in android studio, i am trying to extract an APK from my project, but i can't find any option on android studio to achieve this, these are all the options available in build item:

[image]

In all tutorials, i find people recommend going to **build > build bundle(s)/APK**, but this option is not available in android studio, I am using the latest version, what can be the problem??

Answer (score 1):

the same thing happened to me, the compilation options do not appear because **you do not have the same version of the SDK installed** in android studio that you used in Ionic.